# Как реализовать unixtime без datetime?

Tags: python, unixtimestamp

На курсах дали задание реализовать unixtime. Вот как я реализовала

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = int(input('Enter the number of seconds: '))
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp( timestamp )
print( dt )
```

Но ментор вернул мне задание, потому что ему нужно без использования данной библиотеки. Вопрос как это реализовать без библиотеки..? Может кто-либо с этим помочь...?

Comment: А в чём проблема? В минуте 60 секунд. В часе 60 минут. В сутках 24 часа. В году 365 (366) дней. Немножко занудно, но не вижу ничего принципиально сложного.

Comment: Хотя, конечно, стоит уточнить что значит «реализовать unixtime».

Comment: Я не знаю как это в коде сделать

Comment: Так то я понимаю то что вы писали. Но проблема состоит именно в самом коде. Я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Для начала ответить что вы (и ваш ментор) понимает под фразой «реализовать unixtime». Потому что большинство людей под unixtime подразумевает просто число секунд с начала эпохи. Так что совершенно неясно что вам надо реализовать.

Comment: Он имеет ввиду именно то что вы написали. Т.е. я ввожу определенное количество секунд, а консоль выводит дату

Comment: Я думал по коду который я скинул это должно было быть понятно особенно если читать input

Comment: Очень странно называть это реализацией unixtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нельзя использовать библиотеку **datetime** то можно попробовать использовать модуль **time**:

```
import time

timestamp = int(input('Enter the number of seconds: '))
time_struct = time.gmtime(timestamp) # Преобразуем unixtime в UTC time объект
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time_struct)) # Выводим в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ:ММ:СС
```